# svg grouped elements jointly hover

Tags: css, svg

Is it possible for `hover` on an svg element cause other elements with the same class to hover too without `jQuery`? Or do I have to next the two into an outer group?

I have inside an inline svg the following groups:

```
<g class="class1">
    <path....>
    <path....>
</g>

<g class="class1">
    <path....>
    <path....>
</g>
```

I then have in my CSS:

```
class1 {
 ...
}

class1:hover {
 ...
}
```

Comment: You can use `.class1:hover ~ .class1 { styles goes here... }`.

Comment: But this won't select elements which are previous siblings of the hovered element. It will work for next siblings only. To select previous siblings as well you will need to use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't do it directly, but you can achieve it by adding an `id` to the parent element, no classes needed, like that:

```css
#circles:hover circle{
  fill: Wheat;
}
```

```html
<svg id="circles" width="100" height="260" >
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="Tomato" stroke-width="4" fill="Tomato" />
   <circle cx="50" cy="140" r="40" stroke="Tomato" stroke-width="4" fill="Aquamarine"/>  
</svg>
```